# Как получить количество полных лет из даты?

Tags: php

```
$birthday = "1990-10-03T00:00:00.000000Z" ;
нужно узнать сколько полных лет
$age = 2020 - 1990 = 30;
```

Comment: сколько полных лет и вытянуть год из строки - это разные вещи. если я родился в ноябре 20 года, то 1 января 21-го мне полный месяц будет только, а не полный год

Comment: про функцию explode когда-нибудь слышал?

Comment: @Ипатьев, имхо, тут [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) уместнее

Comment: ну нет, колупаться с секундами - это прошлый век. на самом деле тут уместнее date_create(). понятно что explode тут не при делах совсем, прост удивительно - человек с ларвавелем во всю работает, а про базовые функции языка не слышал